# React-Select: Add custom data attribute to Input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-select, custom-data-attribute

I use ReactJS v18.2 with react-select v5.7.

I want to add a custom attribute (e.g. `data-test`) to the input element of my `<Select/>` component, I could not find something like this in the docs.

For my own custom functional components, it just works to add it to the html tag, e.g.

```
<input type="text" test={XYZ}/>
```

For react-select, it does not show up in the DOM at all. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem and used a workaround to make it work. For that I had to create a custom input component.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Select, { components } from 'react-select'

const CustomInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <components.Input
      {...props}
      data-test="abc" // put the value you want..
    />
  )
}

const CustomSelect = () => {
  return (
    <Select
      components={{ Input: CustomInput }}
      options={[ /* your options here */]}
    />
  )
}

export default CustomSelect
```